# Where does tensorflow log error?

Tags: tensorflow

I use TF v0.12.1 with GPU support on Ubuntu-16.04 64 bits, but have an internal error in my pipeline:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1034, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Failed to run py callback pyfunc_4: see error log.
```

Where does TF log its error messages?

Comment: Can you include more context? What other logs are printed to your shell before and after these lines?

Comment: @saeta I think there is enough context. My question is not about finding a fix for my error, but finding the log.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The log corresponding to that exception should be written to standard error in the process that run the op. The error message is produced by [this code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/f8fcd85b8151d287ad09a9323fabf1c5025775b7/tensorflow/python/lib/core/py_func.cc#L192), which calls [`PyErr_Print()`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/exceptions.html), which renders the current Python exception (in the C API) to standard error.

(Note that if you are using distributed TensorFlow and the [`tf.py_func()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/script_ops/script_language_operators_#py_func) op is placed in a different task, you should look in the standard error for that task for log messages. However, please note that `tf.py_func()` does not work if the op is placed in a different process from the process that created the graph, because it relies on the code for the function being registered in a process-wide registry.)

Comment: IIUC the error log is _in fact_ the (exhaustive) python traceback I _already_ have. (Thanks for the py_func / distributed warning, I read that in the doc today)

Comment: Hmm, it might be hard to distinguish... I'd actually expect there to be three tracebacks: (1) The failure that occurred when the TF op called the body of the `tf.py_func()` op, (2) The traceback for the `Session.run()` call that failed, and (3) The traceback for where the `tf.py_func()` op was created. I think the exception message is telling you to look for more information in (1), which should be printed first. This could probably be made easier to use....